# How to open an email, in the sent box, with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, office-interop

My application sends a templated email with information from a datagridview.

I am trying to send a follow up email.

I'd like the app to open the existing email from my sent items folder (using Outlook 365/Outlook 16) and add text to the top of the already existing email so there's a clear chain of communication.

I have code to find the email within the sent box.

How do I open/display that email so text can be added onto it before it's forwarded?

What I have so far:

```
 private void dvgLogs_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;            
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.Selection item = app.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
            Outlook.Folder sentItems = (Outlook.Folder)app.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            Outlook.Items items = sentItems.Items;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;      
            object folderItem;
            string subjectName = "Regarding " + dgvTickets.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " #" + dgvTickets.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();            
            string filter = "[Subject] = " + subjectName;
            folderItem = items.Find(filter);
            while (folderItem != null)
            {
                mailItem = folderItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (mailItem != null)
                {
                    subjectName += mailItem.Subject;
                }
                folderItem = items.FindNext();
            }
            subjectName = " The following e-mail messages were found: " + subjectName;
            MessageBox.Show(subjectName);
            lblFoundEmail.Text = subjectName;            

        }
```

This seems to find the email and let me know that it found it in my messagebox.

I want it to open the found email.

**EDIT**

This code is not quite what I want, but it's better than the above code where my email was not being displayed.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.Selection item = app.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
            Outlook.Folder sentItems = (Outlook.Folder)app.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            if (app.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled)
            {
                Outlook.Explorer explorer = (Explorer)app.Explorers.Add(item.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
                    as Outlook.Folder, Outlook.OlFolderDisplayMode.olFolderDisplayNormal);
                string subjectName = "Regarding " + dgvTickets.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " #" + dgvTickets.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string filter = "subject:" + "\"" + subjectName + "\"";
                explorer.Search(filter, Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeAllFolders);
                explorer.Display();
            }
        }
```

The above code appears to pop open a new Outlook window, and perform the search (which is more than what it was doing, also, it does find the sent email each time), however it doesn't display the email, instead just another instance of Outlook with the performed search.

I'd like it to use the Outlook window that's already open, and then display the found email.

Comment: You already have the email open in the mailItem variable.

Comment: Or do you mean "open" as in "display"? Cal mailItem.Display();

Comment: Did you add that code inside the loop where you access the Subject property?

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for the suggestion. I did try this but I have something wrong. Unfortunately this gives me an error: "System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Obviously I have it set to null above, but then it should be assigning items it finds to it according to my `while (folderItem!=null)` statement.  I'm a little confused, haha.

Comment: Please show your latest code.

Comment: Code apparently too long for a comment :(.  I've tried `mailItem.Display()` inside the loop, outside the loop, and after the loop.  Inside the loop, nothing happens at all.  After the loop I get the error posted above.

I've tried it inside the if statement, and outside the if statement.  Not sure what I could be doing wrong :(

Comment: Edited original post with updated code - and another minor issue with it :)

Comment: What is your code that attempts to display a message returned from Items.Find/FindNext?